# If everything's denormalized, doesn't that make updates really slow (Author, blog example inside)

Tags: database, database-design, mapreduce, nosql, couchdb

So I'm switching to NoSQL from SQL background. So I know I should be 'denormalizing' here.. So  basically I have a simplified idea of what i have to do;

**Users**
These documents hold authentication info, maybe payment method, username and all kinds of details

**Posts**
These posts are made by users, and in each post, we have to display the username and email of a user. So by method of 'denormalizing', I would put the username and the email of the user into each post s/he makes.

But doesn't this create a problem when the user changes their username or email? Wouldn't I have to retroactively go and update all the posts?

Am I designing this correctly? Or missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In such cases, you're not obliged to denormalize data.

You can store users and posts as separate documents (in the same database):

```
{
  "_id":"alice",
  "email":"alice@wonderland.org"
}

{
  "author":"alice",
  "text":"Alice was beginning to get very tired of sitting by her sister on the bank, and of having nothing to do: once or twice she had peeped into the book her sister was reading, but it had no pictures or conversations in it, 'and what is the use of a book,' thought Alice 'without pictures or conversation?'"
}
```

Then you need a map function telling which field will be used for the join:

```
function(o) {
   if (o.text) {
     emit(o._id, {text:o.text, _id:o.author});
   }
}
```

Then call this view with `include_docs=true` and the ID of the post as the `key`.

Maybe it's an overkill to create an index just for this, but you can probably reuse it for something else useful (like "collating" blog posts and comments).